# Mudar data para data comercial (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, data

Eu preciso mudar a Data do meu banco de dados, considerando a Data Comercial usada na empresa que eu trabalho.

Aqui, um mês comercial está entre `26/M-1/AAAA` e `25/M/AAAA`.
Onde M-1: mês passado.

Por exemplo, hoje a data comercial é `26/08/2017` e `25/09/2017`.

Mas o problema está no intervalo de 26 a 31 (ou 30 ou 28, último dia do mês), porque, nesse intervalo, a data comercial deve ser `26/M/AAAA` e `25/M+1/AAAA`e quando virar o mês, será `26/M-1/AAAA` e `25/M/AAAA` novamente.

Eu criei uma query para isso, mas o problema no intervalo acima não consegui resolver.

```
select 
concat(
(       -- se mes tem 31 dias
        if(month(current_date()) in (1,3,5,7,8,10,12),
            -- então, diff(now() - data_i) <= 5? Se sim, incrementa +1 no mês, se não deixa -1
            if(datediff(current_date(), date_format(concat(year(current_date()),'-',month(current_date()),'-',26),'%Y-%m-%d')) <= 5, date_format(concat(year(current_date()),'-',month(current_date())-0,'-',26),'%d/%m/%Y'),date_format(concat(year(current_date()),'-',month(current_date())-1,'-',26),'%d/%m/%Y')),
        -- se mes n tem 30 dias, ele tem 30 dias?
        if(month(current_date()) in (4,6,9,11),
            -- então, diff(now() - data_i) <= 4? Se sim, incrementa +1 no mês, se não deixa -1
            if(datediff(current_date(), date_format(concat(year(current_date()),'-',month(current_date()),'-',26),'%Y-%m-%d')) <= 4, date_format(concat(year(current_date()),'-',month(current_date())-0,'-',26),'%d/%m/%Y'),date_format(concat(year(current_date()),'-',month(current_date())-1,'-',26),'%d/%m/%Y')),
        -- mes 29
        if(month(current_date()) in (2),
            -- então, diff(now() - data_i) <= 4? Se sim, incrementa +1 no mês, se não deixa -1
            if(datediff(current_date(), date_format(concat(year(current_date()),'-',month(current_date()),'-',26),'%Y-%m-%d')) <= 3, date_format(concat(year(current_date()),'-',month(current_date())-0,'-',26),'%d/%m/%Y'),date_format(concat(year(current_date()),'-',month(current_date())-1,'-',26),'%d/%m/%Y')),
        999)))
    )
,' a ',
(       -- se mes tem 31 dias
        if(month(current_date()) in (1,3,5,7,8,10,12),
            -- então, diff(now() - data_i) <= 5? Se sim, incrementa +1 no mês, se não deixa -1
            if(datediff(current_date(), date_format(concat(year(current_date()),'-',month(current_date()),'-',26),'%Y-%m-%d')) <= 5, date_format(concat(year(current_date()),'-',month(current_date())+1,'-',25),'%d/%m/%Y'),date_format(concat(year(current_date()),'-',month(current_date())+0,'-',25),'%d/%m/%Y')),
        -- se mes n tem 31 dias, ele tem 30 dias?
        if(month(current_date()) in (4,6,9,11),
            -- então, diff(now() - data_i) <= 4? Se sim, incrementa +1 no mês, se não deixa -1
            if(datediff(current_date(), date_format(concat(year(current_date()),'-',month(current_date()),'-',26),'%Y-%m-%d')) <= 4, date_format(concat(year(current_date()),'-',month(current_date())+1,'-',25),'%d/%m/%Y'),date_format(concat(year(current_date()),'-',month(current_date())+0,'-',25),'%d/%m/%Y')),
        if(month(current_date()) in (2),
            -- então, diff(now() - data_i) <= 4? Se sim, incrementa +1 no mês, se não deixa -1
            if(datediff(current_date(), date_format(concat(year(current_date()),'-',month(current_date()),'-',26),'%Y-%m-%d')) <= 3, date_format(concat(year(current_date()),'-',month(current_date())+1,'-',25),'%d/%m/%Y'),date_format(concat(year(current_date()),'-',month(current_date())+0,'-',25),'%d/%m/%Y')),
        999)))
    )
) as 'DataMesComercial'
;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creio que isso possa ajudar no seu caso:

```
SELECT
    (SELECT IF ((DAY(CURDATE()) < 26),
        (SELECT STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('26', '/', MONTH(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)), '/', YEAR(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH))), '%d/%m/%Y')),
        (SELECT STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('26', '/', MONTH(CURDATE()), '/', YEAR(CURDATE())), '%d/%m/%Y')))) AS data_inicial,

    (SELECT IF ((DAY(CURDATE()) < 26),
        (SELECT STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('25', '/', MONTH(CURDATE()), '/', YEAR(CURDATE())), '%d/%m/%Y')),
        (SELECT STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('25', '/', MONTH(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)), '/', YEAR(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH))), '%d/%m/%Y')))) AS data_final;
```

Caso o dia seja menor que 26, ele considera `26/M-1/AAAA e 25/M/AAAA`. Caso contrário, ele vai considerar `26/M/AAAA e 25/M+1/AAAA`.

Comment: Resolveu, obrigado!!!

Comment: Fico feliz em ajudar! :D